Browser html does not match VBA html, why?
If I open Google Chrome and paste
https://meetup.com/cflfreethought/events/301401141/attendees/
into the URL bar, then right click and choose “View Page Source” I get html code.
In the VBA below, the html response text does not match the ‘View Page Source’ html.  Why?
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim url As String
Dim html As String

' Create XMLHTTP object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

' Specify the URL of the webpage
url = "https://meetup.com/cflfreethought/events/301401141/attendees/"

' Make the HTTP request
xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
xmlhttp.send

' Get the response text (HTML source)
html = xmlhttp.responseText


Please have a look onto https://stackoverflow.com/a/78814310/17172829

Thanks.  I've been trying SeleniumBasic but after the install I tried running a small test VB and it says it can't find the chrome binary.  But I see chrome.exe.

Please don't ask a (new) question in the comments. Also do not ask such a question in the comments in several questions. Consider to open a new question (after you have searched for similar topics) (maybe link your previous questions in the new one if necessary/helpfull).

Sorry, I'm new here.
